# Значения позиции для View округляются?

Tags: android, xml, анимация

С View в коде ничего не происходит,она только существует, и я расчитал вручную ее параметры и сравнил с реальными из метода getX() - значения разные.

Код разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
//Значение плотности - 1.5
Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density
```

```
//Реальное местонахождение view- 202.0(в пикселях)
imageView.getX()
```

И расчеты:

ширина экрана- (из документации телефона)`480px=480/1.5=320dp`

ширина view- `50dp=50*1.5=75px`

позиция view(левая верхняя ее точка)-`480/2-75/2=202.5`
Несоответствие с реальной позицией на пол пикселя! И тут никакой придирчивости,потому что при анимировании эти 0.5 пикселя вылазят боком.
Есть предположение что где-то выполняется каст в виде (float)(int),но либо это происходит на   другом уровне, либо это не так

Comment: Но ведь метод `getWidth()` возвращает `int` - естественно значение не может содержать то что после запятой. Или Вам не нравится точность/правило округления?

Comment: @woesss ауч,заметил ошибку(перепутал с getX(),в коде именно он) ,исправил